# Basic set operation questions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

For each collection given below, determine whether the sets are mutually disjoint, whether the collection is nested and find their intersections and unions.

there are three of these and i think i got them solved but i just am unsure.

for

F= { [6-n,6-($\frac{1}{n}$)] | n $\in$ N }

What i was saying is since (6-n) $\cap$ (6-$\frac{1}{n}$) = {5}. these are not mutually disjoint, and I am saying that since 6-n is a subset of 6-(1/n) that the pair in F is nested.  And their intersection is 5 and the union is (6-n) + (6 - 1/n).

Comment: that was just reference, i was just wondering about that problem...

Comment: [a,b] here is meant to represent the set of real numbers $r$ such that $a\leq r\leq b$. The sets will be nested if they form a chain under inclusion, i.e. for any pair of sets in $F$ one is a subset of the other. Try again. For the purposes of the question you are not intended to consider an individual real number as a set (even if you have defined it as such), so $(6-n)\cap(6-\frac{1}{n})$ would be meaningless and certainly not $\{5\}$.

Comment: You should start by listing the first few sets that are elements of $F$.  We have to assume that the first natural number is $1$.  Each value of $n$ gives a closed interval (of $\mathbb{R}$, presumably).   Avoid confusion between elements of $F$, which are intervals, and elements of $\mathbb{R}$, as in "$6-n$ is a subset of $6-(1/n)$."